# grep specific part out of a line of text

Tags: text, grep, line

this is my first question here so please bear with me.
I have a large text file from which I need only one specific part of one line. I can grep the line but I do not know how I can get that specific part out of that line.

here is my text line (stored in output.txt)

```
  ><source src="https://download.foobar.com/content/mp4/web01/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web01.mp4" type="video/mp4" data-label="Laag - 360p"  /><source src="https://download.foobar.com/content/mp4/web02/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web02.mp4" type="video/mp4" data-label="Hoog - 720p"  /><source src="https://download.foobar.com/content/mp4/web03/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web03.mp4" type="video/mp4" data-label="Normaal - 480p"  /></video></div></div>
```

the part I need to extract from this line is:

```
https://download.foobar.com/content/mp4/web02/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web02.mp4
```

Now I can do a grep like this but that gives me back three lines:

```
grep -Po '><source src="\K[^"]+' output.txt
```

gives me:

```
https://download.omroep.nl/nos/content/mp4/web01/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web01.mp4
https://download.omroep.nl/nos/content/mp4/web02/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web02.mp4
https://download.omroep.nl/nos/content/mp4/web03/2017/05/08/24599/mp4_web03.mp4
```

I would like to get only the line I am looking for without making the extra sed command to remove the first and third line of the results.
How can I grep the input line and only get back the intended line. I only need the link to the mp4_web02.mp4 file.

Can anyone help me get this into one grep command?

Comment: Change your search criteria to be more specific.

Comment: How about simply appending the filename to the regex? `grep -Po '><source src="\K[^"]+/mp4_web02\.mp4' output.txt`

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy, but all I found on the internet were difficult solutions that did not work, this one works perfectly, Thanks!